# Display TextInputLayout error at center horizontally

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-textinputlayout

How can I horizontally center the TextInputLayout error?

I have come across a SO post that suggests using reflection to get reference to the error textview. I would like to avoid using reflection.

What are some ways I can accomplish this?

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You make a own class that inherits from TextInputLayout. Then override the ShowError(string text, Drawable icon) method. If the error is called you center the textView with the error.

```
public class TextInputLayout_Center : TextInputLayout
{
    public override void ShowError(string text, Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable icon)
    {
        base.ShowError(text, icon);

        centerErrorMessage(this);
    }

    void centerErrorMessage(ViewGroup view)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < view.ChildCount; i++)
        {
            View v = view.GetChildAt(i);
            if (v.GetType() == typeof(TextView))
            {
                v.LayoutParameters = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, v.LayoutParameters.Height);
                ((TextView)v).Gravity = GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal;
                ((TextView)v).TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
            }
            if (v is ViewGroup)
            {
                centerErrorMessage((ViewGroup)v);
            }
        }
    }
}
```